# How Do I Change The Update Frequency Of The HERE Android SDK PositioningManager?

Tags: android, gps, here-api

I am currently using the Premium SDK Android to acquire GPS positioning in an app.  The `LocationMethod` I am using is `PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS` and this results in updates being received once every second.

I would like to reduce the frequency to something like once every two seconds.  How would I do this?

Comment: Don't try to show it on the map instead call the method which show's the location for every time period by using a timer task or timeout method!

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate and start the the PositionManganer and then retrieve the current position only when you are interested without attaching a position listener:

```
// Instantiate Positioning Manager
PositioningManager positioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();

// Start positioning manager
positioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);

// Now you can get your position any time you desire (within a timer)
GeoPosition gp = PositioningManager.getPosition();
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.16/dev_guide/topics/map-positioning.html